# Possible to hijack class definition with decorators?

Tags: python, decorator

Say I have a

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass
```

and I want an decorator that copies `A`'s definition and extend it with the new class.

```
def decorator(cls): # some decorator here
    # make a new class which inherits from A
    # return it while preserving the original A
```

Is that possible? (PS: This is to avoid maintainence problems.)

Comment: Are you sure you want a new class and not simply "decorating" the existing one? This is called monkey patching and it's a common pattern.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak, Yes, I need two different classes.

Comment: Does it need to go through the decorator or would making a child class be enough? `class ChildClassName (ParentClass1[, ParentClass2, ...]):`

Comment: @DavyM, No it doesn't. But I have many `A`s, so creating one for each is not quite maintainable.

Comment: If you just want a one liner to create a subclass, you can just instantiate the base metaclass `type`. Just do `SA = type('SA', (A,), {})`, but there might be a better solution if you explain why you need to do that.

Comment: @PedroWerneck, to create a variant of an existing class. (Modifying and adding fields and methods of the class while preserving the orignal one.)

Comment: @YiFei: Usually the best way to make a subclass is to just make a subclass with `class SubClass(A):`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke a function using decorator syntax:

```
@my_decorator_function
class A:
    pass
```

The decorator function's return value will replace the existing definition of `A`. So if you want it to create a new class and "return it while preserving the original A", you've got a tricky challenge. What you `return` will replace `A`, so you need to decide if that should be the original `A` or the new class. You can put the other one somewhere else.

For instance, this decorator would replace `A` with a subclass, and the subclass will make the original `A` class available as a class attribute named `_orig`:

```
def class_decorator(cls):
    class SubClass(cls):
        _orig = cls
        # add other stuff here?
    return SubClass
```

You can add extra logic to copy the original class's `__name__` and `__doc__` into the new class if you want to. You could also turn the logic around, and add `SubClass` as an attribute of `cls` before returning the otherwise unmodified `cls`.

Comment: This is fascinating! I think the better way for me is to keep the new class as an attribute of original class. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Using `@decorator` is not the only possible syntax.  You can put `B = decorator(A)` after the class definition.

```
class A:
    ...

B = decorator(A)
```

Now you still have a reference on the undecorated `A`, and you have a decorated version `B`.

Comment: Good enough, but it'll be better if I could automate it with a single statement on `A` like a decorator... Though I got to admit that's merely a syntactic sugar. Thanks.

Comment: It's technically possible, but you have to decide what name points to the plain class and what name points to the decorated class (and you have to describe how that should work in the question).  Because `A` can't point to both the old class and the new one.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have done a good job, but to make it crystal clear why you don't want to do this:

```
def dec(cls):
    new_cls = type(cls.__name__, (cls,), {})
    return new_cls

@dec
class A():
    pass
```

Now inspect the method resolution order class `A`:

```
>>> A.__mro__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> classes = A.__mro__
>>> classes[0].__name__
'A'
>>> classes[1].__name__
'A'
```

TWO class `A`s! Are they the same?

```
>>> classes[0] is classes[1]
False
```

Nope; different. The current variable `A` is pointing to the lowest one of course:

```
>>> A is classes[0]
True
```

But now you've lost name-access to the parent. That's usually not optimal.

In short: you are creating a metric ton of confusion and ambiguity for yourself a few months from now when you have forgotten all about what you did. Do something else.

If you really want to, here is an idea for spinning out new subclasses:

```
def add_babymaker(cls):
    '''Adds a method for making new child classes.'''
    def babymaker(name=None):
        '''Creates a new child class based on the parent class.'''
        name = name if name is not None else cls.__name__
        new_cls = type(name, (cls,), {})
        return new_cls
    cls.babymaker = babymaker
    return cls

@add_babymaker
class A():
    pass

B = A.babymaker('B')
C = A.babymaker('C')
ANew = A.babymaker()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have worked it out. That's not really a good idea.

```
def make_variant(cls):
    suffix='VARIANT'
    new = type(cls.__name__+suffix, (cls, ), {})
    # new.__repr__ = lambda self: 'HELLO' # Just do whatever needed here
    assert cls.__name__ + suffix not in globals()
    globals()[cls.__name__+suffix] = new # Think twice about this line
    return cls

@make_variant
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

print(AVARIANT(), A())
```

Comment: A decorator that dumps new names into globals is not a palatable idea.  That's just not what people expect decorators to do, and will likely make IDEs and linters go haywire (thinking you have unresolved names).  I can't believe this approach is going to help "avoid maintainence problems", more like create them ...

Comment: @wim, Agreed, that it solves the problem doesn't mean it don't make more... Blckknght's solution is great btw.